# Want to execute one complex Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get the result set only by one query if possible 
i have table like that

```
    ------------------------------
    user_id | activity_id | score 
    ------------------------------
        1   |      1      |  100
    ------------------------------
        1   |      1      |  50
    ------------------------------
        1   |      2      |  20
    ------------------------------
        1   |      3      |  10
    ------------------------------
        1   |      3      |  50
    ------------------------------
        2   |      1      |  300
    ------------------------------
        3   |      3      |  10
    ------------------------------
        3   |      2      |  40
    ------------------------------
```

All what i need to select each user with sum of all of his high score in each activity.
for example the result set should be like that:

```
    ------------------------------
    user_id | score 
    ------------------------------
        1   |  170
    ------------------------------
        2   |  300
    ------------------------------
        3   |  50
    ------------------------------
```

Comment: Already ask : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: The user_id with the hightest score grouping by activity is the same that the content with the hightest version grouping by id

Comment: i want the sum of highest score ... like the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the highest score for each user/activity pair, you would use the following query:

```
select user_id, activity_id, max(score) as highscore
from t
group by user_id, activity_id;
```

To add these up for a given user, you would make this a subquery and do another aggregation:

```
select user_id, sum(highscore)
from (select user_id, activity_id, max(score) as highscore
      from t
      group by user_id, activity_id
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

Comment: what if i want to join with table user to get user name for example ?